# Qt SIGNAL->SLOTS mechanizm

Tags: c++, qt

I have some C++ code with Qt 4 functions:

```
QColorDialog colordialog0(&window0);
colordialog0.show();

QPixmap pixmap0(10, 10);
QObject::connect(&colordialog0, SIGNAL(colorSelected(const QColor &)), &pixmap0, SLOT(fill(const QColor &)));
```

When I build a project, it compiled with error:

```
error C2665: 'QObject::connect' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
    \qt\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h(204): could be 'bool QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)'
    \qt\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h(217): or       'bool QObject::connect(const QObject *,const QMetaMethod &,const QObject *,const QMetaMethod &,Qt::ConnectionType)'
    \qt\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h(231): or       'bool QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const'
    while trying to match the argument list '(QColorDialog *, const char *, QPixmap *, const char *)'
```

I couldn't understand this, because when I compile another code (without Q_OBJECT, moc files and other):

```
QFileDialog filedialog0;
filedialog0.show();

QLabel label0(&centralwidget0);
QObject::connect(&filedialog0, SIGNAL(fileSelected(const QString &)), &label0, SLOT(setText(const QString &)));
```

it is not errors. I know that reason is in overloaded functions. So, how can I compile (VS2008) with only one func?

Thanks.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QPixmap does not have a fill() slot.

You could do a wrapper and make your own slots. Or find a better class for what you want to do.

Comment: Also, QPixmap is not a QObject, so I cannot have slots.